# Intel Parallel Studio use only 2GB RAM

Tags: c++, profiling, intel, inspector

I have large project and I want to debug it with IPS (Inspector). But my project by default eat about 1 Gb RAM and with Inspector it try to eat more then 2Gb RAM. So, I have 16 Gb RAM installed but when Inspector eat more then 2 GB of them it stops debugging and say what memory limit was exceeded. How I can increase memory limit for Intel Inspector?

Comment: Are you working on a Windows 32 bit system?

Comment: x64 but my application is x32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32-bit systems can address up to 2GB of memory per process (technically 2^31), regardless of how much memory exists in the system, so perhaps this is the reason your process never exceeds that limit.

In addition, *even if* your computer system is 64-bit, it's possible your process is itself 32-bit. In this case, the same thing as above applies. You'd need to recompile your application in x64 to be able to take advantage of the extra memory available in your system.

Comment: Technically, if you link with `LARGEADDRESSAWARE`, a x64 application can use more than 2GB, but not quite up to 4GB. (And 3GB in a 32-bit OS when enabling 3GB user-space)

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Thanks, good point. I think you meant to say x86 application though.

Comment: well, I meant "a 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS".

Comment: djikay answer is accurate. If your 32bit app is already consuming more than 1 Gb of RAM, then you will be much closer to 2 Gb boundary with Inspector XE. In such cases the "official answer" from Inspector XE forums would mostly always be - consider recompiling your application for x64. While on Windows Inspector XE GUI is 32bits process, it's perfectly and seamlessly capable of profiling/dispatching both 32bits and 64bits target applications